# Does calcium carbonate remove calcium from our bones?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, elements

Is it true that milk contains **calcium carbonate** which *removes calcium from our bones* so we shouldn't drink it?

Comment: Your bones are made of calcium carbonate. Milk is a good source of calcium and is considered to be perfectly healthy to drink.

Comment: I object. Bones are made of calcium _phosphate_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You're right! I have always believed that it is calcium carbonate but that seems like a myth.

Comment: You would need [HF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrofluoric_acid#Health_and_safety) for that.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it doesn't contain calcium carbonate. Calcium carbonate is solid material that doesn't solve in water. Marble and limestone are calcium carbonate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate).

Even if it contained, it would be an excellent source of calcium. It is even used as dietary supplement. 
https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Calcium-HealthProfessional/

To answer the implied question (can you drink milk?), @Curt Fs's reference is perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, milk is a [perfectly viable source of dietary calcium](http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/calcium-full-story/).